# overflow auto is unable to correct the image

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 600px;
}

img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quaerat id asperiores at ad odit aperiam harum repellendus commodi magni, modi eligendi iure veniam ipsam dolorem dolor nesciunt consectetur quia eveniet possimus quibusdam laborum est explicabo? Autem optio obcaecati ducimus, maxime cum molestias, vero facere esse corporis accusantium aperiam
  </span>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
</div>
```

[image]

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vb5jn2tw/18/

Am I missing anything? The image should not cover the text.

Comment: How does your layout should look like?

Comment: Its in the attached screenshot

Comment: I see only the screenshot with the problem, but not the desirable layout.

Comment: The image should not overlay the text. Thats the outcome  I am expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the `float:left`, which "moves" the image from just behind **aperiam** to the left side of the page.

Changing it to `display:block` could already do what you want:

```css
div {
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 600px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quaerat id asperiores at ad odit aperiam harum repellendus commodi magni, modi eligendi iure veniam ipsam dolorem dolor nesciunt consectetur quia eveniet possimus quibusdam laborum est explicabo? Autem optio obcaecati ducimus, maxime cum molestias, vero facere esse corporis accusantium aperiam
  </span>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add Following line in your css.

```css
div {
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: yellow; 
  height: 600px;
}
div span{display:block}
img {
  float: left;  
}
```

```html
<div>

  <span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quaerat id asperiores at ad odit aperiam harum repellendus commodi magni, modi eligendi iure veniam ipsam dolorem dolor nesciunt consectetur quia eveniet possimus quibusdam laborum est explicabo? Autem optio obcaecati ducimus, maxime cum molestias, vero facere esse corporis accusantium aperiam
  </span>
    <img src = "https://picsum.photos/100" />
</div>
```